# Why google sheets is not calculating the XIRR?

Tags: google-sheets, xirr

[Sample Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOPVr.png)

I am trying the XIRR formula on a very basic data but not sure why system is not calculating it.
I am using formula for individual cell =XIRR(I2,C2) and for total =XIRR(I2:I4,C2:C4). Please guide how can I correct or what wrong I am doing in it.

Thanks